# ASP .NET MVC: How can I change the role of an user?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In my app I have an Administrator role, and these kind of users can change the role of a user(client, manager...). I am using the built in Membership provider. Here is what I tried to do...

```
        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult EditRole(string usernameID, FormCollection formValues)
    {

        var db = new AppDataContext();
        var user = db.Users.SingleOrDefault(d => d.UserName == usernameID);
        string choosenRole = Request.Form["Roles"];                               

        var tuple = db.UsersInRoles.SingleOrDefault(d => d.UserId == user.UserId);
        var roleNameID = db.Roles.SingleOrDefault(d => d.RoleName == choosenRole).RoleId;
        tuple.RoleId = roleNameID;

        db.SubmitChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

But, I got this error..

> Value of member 'RoleId' of an object of type 'UsersInRole' changed.
>   A member defining the identity of the object cannot be changed.
>   Consider adding a new object with new identity and deleting the existing one instead.

I'm stucked. Any ideas?

Comment: are you using the built in Membership provider or managing users/roles yourself?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Rather than trying to access the membership tables directly from the db (datacontext) you should be using the `User`, `Roles`, and `Membership` static classes provided within your action code there.

Like this:

```
System.Web.Security.Roles.AddUserToRole(usernameID, choosenRole);
```

Assuming that your usernameID is the string key of the user you want to change and choosenRole contains the role name key you want to add the user to:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult EditRole(string usernameID, FormCollection formValues)
{
    string choosenRole = Request.Form["Roles"];                               
    System.Web.Security.Roles.AddUserToRole(usernameID, choosenRole);

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I did not get it. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 0):

`UsersInRole.RoleId` is part of the primary key of the `UsersInRole` table and can therefore not be changed. You should follow the suggestion given by the error message and delete the existing `UsersInRole` instance and create a new one.

Comment: So it is not possible and I have to rebuild the Membership of the user?

Comment: Yes, it is not possible. So you could delete and create a new UsersInRole instance or follow the suggestion from cottsak (use the Membership classes).

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I was able to change the role for a user.
I first create the roleStore and the roleManager to be able to manage roles. I then checked to see if the role does exist and if not, add (Just to make sure I get no null). I then removed the role from the user and then I added the role I wanted.

Keep in mind that User.Identity.GetUserId() gets the ID of the currently logged in user. If you want to change the role for someone else, you need to find their UserId.

```
ApplicationUser au = dbContext.Users.Find(User.Identity.GetUserId());
var roleStore = new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(new ApplicationDbContext());
var roleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(roleStore);
IdentityRole search_role = roleManager.FindByName(ae_auvm.UserRole);

if (search_role == null)
{
    await roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole(ae_auvm.UserRole.Trim()));
}

string[] roleNames = userManager.GetRoles(au.Id).ToArray();

UserManager.RemoveFromRoles(au.Id, roleNames);
roleNames = userManager.GetRoles(au.Id).ToArray();

await UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(au.Id, ae_auvm.UserRole.Trim());
roleNames = userManager.GetRoles(au.Id).ToArray();
```